How can you access a dynamic related list from an object?
I have a dynamic related list "Qualified Contacts" in my Account object, that filters contacts based on tenure (custom field).  I want to access this filtered list in a trigger, however I can't seem to find it as Account.Qualified_Contact__c like other fields, how can I do this?

The Dynamic Related List component renders filtered list of records at run-time, it isn't actually a filtered list in the background like the full related lists.
This means you can't access these in Apex.

I'm afraid that was the answer, thank you
